# Meaning of H/5 in cron Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cron

I have a job with as cron:

```
5 3,21 * * 1-5
```

This will run my job at 03:05AM and 09:05PM. Now I read it's a best practice to use `H`.

I try:

```
H/5 3,21 * * 1-5
```

What is the meaning now? Will this schedule a build in a range of 5 minutes or 5 minutes after 3AM and 21PM?

Comment: Modern versions of Jenkins will tell you what the "next" and "previous" launches will be. Change the setting and look at the window below it.  E.g. with `H/20 * * * *` it says this
`Would last have run at Sunday, June 5, 2022 at 6:03:23 PM Coordinated Universal Time; would next run at Sunday, June 5, 2022 at 6:23:23 PM Coordinated Universal Time.`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The `H` will take a numeric hash of the Job name and use this to ensure that different jobs with the same cron settings do not all trigger at the same time. This is a form of [Scheduling Jitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336454/what-is-scheduling-jitter)

`H/5` in the first field means **Every five minutes starting at some time between 0 and 4 minutes past the hour**

So `H/5 3,21 * * 1-5`

is **Every five minutes between 03:00 and 03:59 and then between 21:00 and 21:59 on Mon -> Fri** but starting at some 'random' time between 03:00 and 03:04 and then the same number of minutes after 21:00

If you want to run once per hour between 03:00-03:59 and 21:00-21:59 on Mon -> Fri, you can use `H 3,21 * * 1-5` where `H` will be replaced by some number between 0-59 depending on job name.

The user interface will tell you when the job will last have triggered and will next trigger

Comment: So this does not mean start between 2.55 and 3.05 a build AND start a build between 20.55 and 21.05?

Comment: H/5 3,21 * * 1-5 is telling me it would start a build around 3AM and around 21PM (not between them). But thanks for the info. I understand now I think. You can edit it and I'll accept

Comment: But H/5 will do it every 5 mins during the hours 3:xx and 21:xx. If you want it just once in those hours just use H on its own

Comment: You're right. Is it possible to run it like I described in my initial case but using 'H'? So run it twice around 3AM and around 9PM?

Comment: Correct "Around" means "Between 0 and 59 minutes after" It won't run at 02:59 . If you're happy with my answer would you mind marking it as accepted?

Comment: Thanks, I think I need something like: H(0-5)/1 21 * * 1-5 (run between 5 minutes after 9PM?

Comment: The /1 will try and run it every minute. I think `H(0-5) 21 * * 1-5 is what you're after

Comment: What would happen if ‘different jobs with the same cron settings do all trigger at the same time’

Comment: It might contend for resources with your available agents.