# Job scheduling using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We have a multibranch pipeline for our Jenkins job configuration. We have three branches: `develop`, `master` and feature branch. Developers want to run feature branch periodically every day. We are using same Jenkinsfile for several projects.

For running periodically, I have added below lines to my feature branch.

```
properties([[$class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '10', 
    artifactNumToKeepStr: '10', daysToKeepStr: '10', numToKeepStr: '10']], gitLabConnection('GitLab'), pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'TimerTrigger', spec: '0 5,12 * * *']])])
```

The problem is that we have 5 projects and all of them are being executed at the same time as they are using same Jenkinsfile. Is there any way that I can run those projects one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try prefixing the trigger with 'H/' spec: `spec: 'H 5,12 * * *'` instead of `spec: '0 5,12 * * *'`

Jenkins evenly distributes the jobs when multiple jobs have same pattern that trigger at same time.

[Meaning of H prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302607/meaning-of-h-5-in-cron-jenkins) is explained here.

Comment: Great Info..! Meaning of H prefix I see that **H/5 in the first field means Every five minutes starting at some time between 0 and 4 minutes past the hour** so if i keep H/0 will it run randomly in that 0-59 sec? thanks again

Comment: Well, I think you should use H 5,12 * * *.
This represents Jenkins build to run once at given hour every day.

Comment: Actually, I would like to run morning 6 am and afternoon 4pm everyday. 
 @dot

Comment: In that case it would be H 6,16 * * *