# How to set two different scheduler for single Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, cron, continuous-integration

I just want to run the job twice per week. Every Sunday 11 PM and every Friday 11 pm I just want to trigger the job automatically. I successfully implemented for one scheduler but not sure how to use two in single .

```
    Sunday scheduler :

      H 11 * * 0 

    Friday scheduler:

      H 11 * * 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Note there's a couple changes from your example, changed 11 to 23, 11 is 11am, 23 is 11pm and using 5 instead of 6 for Friday.

```
H 23 * * 0,5
```

But note with the "H" it isn't going to run at exactly 11pm, from the Jenkins docs:

> The H symbol can be thought of as a random value over a range, but it
>   actually is a hash of the job name, not a random function, so that the
>   value remains stable for any given project.

If you want it to run closer to 11pm, maybe something like this

```
H(1-5) 23 * * 0,5
```

Answer (score 1):

For scheduling the job below pattern need to be followed:-

```
0 - Sun      Sunday
1 - Mon      Monday
2 - Tue      Tuesday
3 - Wed      Wednesday
4 - Thu      Thursday
5 - Fri      Friday
6 - Sat      Saturday
7 - Sun      Sunday
```

For your case you can follow the below:-

> 0 23 * * 0,5

You better understanding of "H" in Jobs Scheduler [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302607/meaning-of-h-5-in-cron-jenkins):